# SQl calculate percentage avoid Div/0 error in Stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, percentage, divide-by-zero

I'm trying to update some old stored procedures which are currently hit and miss as to whether they work.

It pulls in data from several tables to create a recordset for a table based report.

The problem I have is with the Utilisation figures, these are percentages but they often run into the Divide by Zero error.

Here's the current script.

```
CREATE PROC [PPA].[MonthlyUtilisation]

--EXEC [PPA].[MonthlyUtilisationIndividual] @Year = 1920, @Employee = 7238734, @Month = 5, @Area = 'National', @Team = 'SET'

@Year int,
@Employee int,
@Month int,
@Area varchar(55),
@Team varchar(55)

AS

DECLARE @MonthID int = (SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT([ReportYear],[ReportMonth]) FROM [PPA].[Weeks] WHERE [ReportYear] = @Year AND [ReportMonth] = @Month)

SELECT 
Ep.[EmployeePID] AS [Staff PID]
,E.[FirstName] AS [First Name]
,E.[LastName] AS [Last Name]
,G.[GradeName] AS [Staff Grade]
,Tms.[TeamName] As [Team]
,Count(Ep.[EmployeePID]) AS [*]
,Sum([WeeklyContractedHours]) AS [GROSS Available Resource]
,Isnull(Sum(f.mins), 0) AS [Planned Flexi]
,Isnull(Sum(af.mins), 0) AS [Actual Flexi]
,Isnull(Sum(l.mins), 0) AS [Planned Leave]
,Isnull(Sum(al.mins), 0) AS [Actual Leave]

,Sum([WeeklyContractedHours] 
+ Isnull(f.mins, 0) 
- Isnull(l.mins, 0))
AS [Planned NET Available Resource]

,Sum([WeeklyContractedHours] 
+ Isnull(af.mins, 0) 
- Isnull(al.mins, 0))
AS [Actual NET Available Resource]

,Isnull(Sum(i.mins), 0) AS [Planned Indirects]
,Isnull(Sum(ai.mins), 0) AS [Actual Indirects]

,Sum([WeeklyContractedHours]
+ Isnull(f.mins, 0)
- Isnull(l.mins, 0))
- Isnull(Sum(i.mins), 0)
AS [Planned GROSS Direct Resource]

,Sum([WeeklyContractedHours]
+ Isnull(af.mins, 0)
- Isnull(al.mins, 0))
- Isnull(Sum(ai.mins), 0)
AS [Actual GROSS Direct Resource]

,Round(Cast(Sum([WeeklyContractedHours]
+ Isnull(f.mins, 0) 
- Isnull(l.mins, 0)) 
- Isnull(Sum(i.mins), 0) AS FLOAT) 
/ Cast(Sum([WeeklyContractedHours] 
+ Isnull(f.mins, 0) 
- Isnull(l.mins, 0)) AS FLOAT) 
* 100, 0)
AS [Planned Utilisation]
 
,Round(Cast(Sum([WeeklyContractedHours] 
+ Isnull(af.mins, 0) 
- Isnull(al.mins, 0)) 
- Isnull(Sum(ai.mins), 0) AS FLOAT) 
/ Cast(Sum([WeeklyContractedHours] 
+ Isnull(af.mins, 0) 
- Isnull(al.mins, 0)) AS FLOAT) 
* 100, 0)
AS [Actual Utilisation]
  
FROM [PPA].[EmployeeProfiles] AS Ep 
/*=====================================
======================================*/

LEFT JOIN [PPA].[Timesheets] as Ts on Ts.[EmployeeProfileID] = Ep.[EmployeeProfileID]
LEFT JOIN [PPA].[employees] AS E ON Ep.[EmployeePID] = E.[EmployeePID] 
JOIN [PPA].[grades] AS G ON Ep.[GradeID] = G.[GradeID]
JOIN [PPA].[teams] as Tms ON Ep.[TeamID] = Tms.[TeamID]
JOIN [PPA].[areas] as A ON Tms.[AreaID] = A.[AreaID]
JOIN [PPA].[Weeks] as Wk on Ts.[WeekID] = wk.[WeekID]

--Planned Flexi Leave
LEFT JOIN (SELECT T.[TimesheetID],
Isnull(Sum(mins), 0) AS Mins 
FROM [PPA].[Stage1Leave] AS S1L 
JOIN [PPA].[timesheets] AS T ON S1L.[TimesheetID] = T.[TimesheetID]
JOIN [PPA].[Weeks] as Wk ON T.[WeekID] = wk.[WeekID]
WHERE  LeaveID = 10
AND Wk.[ReportYear]= @Year and Wk.[ReportMonth] = @Month
GROUP  BY T.[TimesheetID]) AS f 
ON f.[TimesheetID] = Ts.[TimesheetID]

--Actual Flexi Leave
LEFT JOIN (SELECT T.[TimesheetID],
Isnull(Sum(mins), 0) AS Mins 
FROM [PPA].[Stage3Leave] AS S3L 
JOIN [PPA].[timesheets] AS T ON S3L.[TimesheetID] = T.[TimesheetID]
JOIN [PPA].[Weeks] as Wk ON T.[WeekID] = wk.[WeekID]
WHERE  LeaveID = 10
AND Wk.[ReportYear]= @Year and Wk.[ReportMonth] = @Month
GROUP  BY T.[TimesheetID]) AS af 
ON af.[TimesheetID] = Ts.[TimesheetID]

--Planned Leave
LEFT JOIN (SELECT T.[TimesheetID],
Isnull(Sum(mins), 0) AS Mins 
FROM  [PPA].[Stage1Leave] AS S1L
JOIN [PPA].[timesheets] AS T ON S1L.[TimesheetID] = T.[TimesheetID]
JOIN [PPA].[Weeks] as Wk on T.[WeekID] = wk.[WeekID]
WHERE  LeaveID NOT IN (10, 12)
AND Wk.[ReportYear]= @Year and Wk.[ReportMonth] = @Month 
GROUP  BY T.[TimesheetID]) AS l 
ON l.[TimesheetID] = Ts.[TimesheetID] 

--Actual Leave
LEFT JOIN (SELECT T.[TimesheetID], 
Isnull(Sum(mins), 0) AS Mins 
FROM   [PPA].[Stage3Leave] AS S3L 
JOIN [PPA].[timesheets] AS T ON S3L.[TimesheetID] = T.[TimesheetID]
JOIN [PPA].[Weeks] as Wk on T.[WeekID] = wk.[WeekID]
WHERE  LeaveID <> 10
AND Wk.[ReportYear]= @Year and Wk.[ReportMonth] = @Month
GROUP  BY T.[TimesheetID]) AS al 
ON al.[TimesheetID] = Ts.[TimesheetID] 

--Planned Indirects
LEFT JOIN (SELECT T.[TimesheetID], 
Isnull(Sum(mins), 0) AS Mins 
FROM   [PPA].[stage1] AS S 
JOIN [PPA].[timesheets] AS T ON S.[TimesheetID] = T.[TimesheetID]
JOIN [PPA].[Weeks] as Wk on T.[WeekID] = wk.[WeekID]
WHERE Wk.[ReportYear]= @Year and Wk.[ReportMonth] = @Month
GROUP  BY T.[TimesheetID]) AS i 
ON i.[TimesheetID] = Ts.[TimesheetID]

--Actual Indirects
LEFT JOIN (SELECT T.[TimesheetID], 
Isnull(Sum(mins), 0) AS Mins 
FROM   [PPA].[stage3indirects] AS s3i
JOIN [PPA].[timesheets] AS T ON s3i.[TimesheetID] = T.[TimesheetID]
JOIN [PPA].[Weeks] as Wk on T.[WeekID] = wk.[WeekID]
WHERE Wk.[ReportYear]= @Year and Wk.[ReportMonth] = @Month
GROUP  BY T.[TimesheetID]) AS ai 
ON ai.[TimesheetID] = Ts.[TimesheetID]

WHERE Ts.[EmployeePID] = CASE WHEN @Employee = 0 THEN Ts.[EmployeePID] ELSE @Employee END
AND Tms.[TeamName] = CASE WHEN @Team = 'All' THEN [TeamName] ELSE @Team END
--AND (SELECT CONCAT([ReportYear],[ReportMonth])) = @MonthID
AND Wk.[ReportYear]= @Year and Wk.[ReportMonth] = @Month
and Ep.[Live] = 1
GROUP  BY Tms.[TeamName]
,G.[GradeName] 
,G.[GradeID]
,E.[LastName]
,E.[FirstName] 
,Ep.[EmployeePID]
ORDER  BY Tms.[TeamName], G.[GradeID]

GO
```

This is the part of the script I'm struggling with

```
,Round(Cast(Sum([WeeklyContractedHours]
+ Isnull(f.mins, 0) 
- Isnull(l.mins, 0)) 
- Isnull(Sum(i.mins), 0) AS FLOAT) 
/ Cast(Sum([WeeklyContractedHours] 
+ Isnull(f.mins, 0) 
- Isnull(l.mins, 0)) AS FLOAT) 
* 100, 0)
AS [Planned Utilisation]
 
,Round(Cast(Sum([WeeklyContractedHours] 
+ Isnull(af.mins, 0) 
- Isnull(al.mins, 0)) 
- Isnull(Sum(ai.mins), 0) AS FLOAT) 
/ Cast(Sum([WeeklyContractedHours] 
+ Isnull(af.mins, 0) 
- Isnull(al.mins, 0)) AS FLOAT) 
* 100, 0)
AS [Actual Utilisation]
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method, in my opinion is wrap the divisor with `NULLIF` so that the value becomes `NULL` if it has a value of `0`.

For example:

```sql
SomeColumn / NULLIF(AnotherColumn - MoreColumn,0)
```

*Side note, please consider making **good** use of white space when writing SQL. That code is very difficult to read.*